# zf2 - gmail smtp not working

Tags: php, email, zend-framework2, smtp

My previous smtp setting for sending mail was as below and works fine.

```
$options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(array(
    'name' => 'gmail.com',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port' => 465,
    'connection_class' => 'login',
    'connection_config' => array(
        'username' => 'myname@mywebsite.com',
        'password' => 'password',
        'ssl'=> 'ssl',
    ),
));

$transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);
$transport->send($mail);
```

But if i use another account as

```
$options = new Mail\Transport\SmtpOptions(array(
    'name' => 'gmail.com',
    'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
    'port'=> 465,
    'connection_class' => 'login',
    'connection_config' => array(
        'username' => 'mynewname@gmail.com',
        'password' => 'newpassword',
        'ssl'=> 'ssl',
    ),
));

$transport = new Mail\Transport\Smtp($options);
$transport->send($mail);
```

it gives error shown below

[image]

What am i doing wrong.Please help. I'm new to zend.

Comment: Which hosting provider's service you are using?

Comment: It's of one of our client.I dont have that much idea about it. Might be GoDaddy

Comment: If it's godaddy than they have closed 465 port to force you to use their own smtp server.

Comment: Try this link to test your server's port is open or closed : http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola: Thnks , but it works well for the first case,mentioned in the question.

Comment: @nilesh Didn't you turn on the two step authentication for second account?

Comment: Most likely the answer is in the message https://support.google.com/mail/answer/78754?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I had created an autoload file as `mail.local.php` with the following content, its worked for me!

```
return array(
'smtp' => array(
    'transport' => array(
        'options' => array(
            'host' => 'smtp.gmail.com',
            'connection_class' => 'plain',
            'port' => '587',
            'connection_config' => array(
                'username' => 'my-gmail-email-d',
                'password' => 'my-email-password',
                'ssl' => 'tls'
            ),
        ),
    ),
)
```

);

Can you check by changing the port from `465` to `587` and by removing `'connection_class' => 'login'`?